# What's the best way to create a nested div with both an input and label, then assign events on the input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to dynamically create a div, then create a label and input within that div, then assign event handlers (using jQuery's $.on() function) to the input element. What's a good way to go about creating the elements and assigning the events? I'm using the latest version of jQuery. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
$div = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'myclass', click: function(){ ... } }),
$label = ...,
$input = ...

$div.append($label.add($input)).insertAfter('#el')
```

Comment: What element is #el referring to? also, I want to assign a change function to the input element, not the div. Thanks for your response!

Comment: `...` there means ditto, same as above but with `input` instead of `div`. `#el` is whatever container you want that already exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I have done complete solution for above solution, here is demo link:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp91

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <input type="button" id="btnadd" name="btnadd" value="Add Div" />
  <input type="button" id="btnreset" name="btnreset" value="Reset" />
  <br/>
</div>
```

** CSS:**

```
input[type=button]{
  border:1px solid #2233fd;
  background:#2288cb;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
input[type=button]:hover{
  background:#22abde;
}
.mydiv{
  border:1px solid #2255aa;
  padding:5px;
  margin-bottom:7px;
  font-size:13px;
  background:#2275bd;
}
.mydiv input{
  border:1px solid #333;
}
.mydiv label{
  color:#fdf889;
}
.val{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:8px;
  color:#bcfaac;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#btnadd").click(function() {
        if ($("#panel").find("div.mydiv").length) {
            i = $("#panel").find("div.mydiv").length;
        }
        $("#panel").append("<div id='div-" + i + "' class='mydiv'></div>");

        $("div.mydiv:last").append("<label>Enter Value:</label>");
        $("div.mydiv:last").append("<input type='text' name='txt" + i + "' id='txt" + i + "' size='20'/><span class='val'></span>");

        //bind Blur Event
        $("div.mydiv:last").find("input[type=text]").on('blur', function() {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                $(this).parents(".mydiv").find("span.val").html("This Input Contains Value: \"" + $.trim($(this).val()) + "\"");
            } else {
                $(this).parents(".mydiv").find("span.val").html("This Input has been left empty..!");
            }

        });

        i++;

    });
   //Reset List
    $("#btnreset").click(function() {
        $("div.mydiv", $("#panel")).remove();
    });
});
```

The another Alternate way to bind event with element is as below:

first you have to make function that you want to bind.

```
function bindTextbox(){
   if ($(this).val() != "") {
                    $(this).parents(".mydiv").find("span.val").html("This Input Contains Value: \"" + $.trim($(this).val()) + "\"");
                } else {
                    $(this).parents(".mydiv").find("span.val").html("This Input has been left empty..!");
                }
}
```

Write following line script below comment //bind Blur Event on above jQuery script

```
$("div.mydiv:last").find("input[type=text]").bind('blur','bindTextbox');
```

Instead of the following lines of code:

```
 $("div.mydiv:last").find("input[type=text]").on('blur', function() {
     if ($(this).val() != "") {
                    $(this).parents(".mydiv").find("span.val").html("This Input Contains Value: \"" + $.trim($(this).val()) + "\"");
      } else {
                    $(this).parents(".mydiv").find("span.val").html("This Input has been left empty..!");
      }
 });
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp91